# Lit: Update on reflected attribute change

Tags: lit

I have a custom element: `my-form`, which renders another custom element: `my-select`.

`my-select` has a property called `option-checked`. This property is defined with `{ reflect: true }`, so when an option is checked its attribute is updated in the DOM.

```
@customElement('my-form')
export class MyForm extends LitElement {

  // ...

  render() {
    return html`
      <my-select
        .options=${this.options}
        option-checked="foo"
      ></my-select>
    `;
  }
}
```

In the `my-form` custom element I want to watch for changes to the `option-checked` attribute and update when this happens.

How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@lit-labs/observers?

Comment: The solution was to dispatch a custom event from `my-select`.